# SFTP to Bitnami Wordpress in AWS

Tags: putty, amazon-web-services, filezilla, wordpress

I followed this tutorial to install Wordpress by Birnami in AWS https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-bitnami-wordpress/doc/wordpress-high-availability-by-bitnami-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf

Using putty (in Win10) I can SSH to the Bastion instance and from here SSH the Bitnami instance using this https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/infrastructure/lamp-production-ready/get-started/connect-ssh/

My problem: I want to use Filezilla to access vía SFTP the Bitnami instance but all can do is access the Bastion instance. How can I reach this? I need to upload/download files from the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Filezilla doesn't have a builtin ssh tunnel, you need to "create" your own SSH tunnel.

You need to run this command on your bastion instance:

> **ssh -R 2222:Bitnami_instance_IP_Address:22  Bastion_IP_Address**

```
Example:
Bitnami_instance_IP_Address: 10.10.1.10
Bastion_IP_Address: 10.10.1.21

Command will look like this:

# ssh -R 2222:10.10.1.10:22 10.10.1.21
```

Important: Make sure that **GatewayPorts** is set to **yes** in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (GatewayPorts yes) on your Bastion instance.

Once you are done, set your SFTP port on your Filezilla to port **2222**